# How to encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key in c# RSA

Tags: .net, cryptography, rsa

I found several solutions where I can use the .Net RSA Provider to Encrypt a message with the public key and Decrypt it with the private one.

But what I want to have is to Encrypt with the private key and Decrypt with the public key.

I want t store the public key in my app and encrypt a license for example on my dev machine with the private key, send it to the app and let the information decrypt with a public key.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't. You can only encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key. What you mean is signature and verification, which is a valid application for a license. You get authentication, but **no** confidentiality. If you want to make that interactive you can of course achieve more.

Comment: **Asymmetric encryption/decryption:** everyone can encrypt (using a public key), only the host can decrypt (using a private key). **Asymmetric signature/verification:** only the host can sign (using a private key), everyone can verify (using a public key).

Comment: Did you check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38739/RSA-Private-Key-Encryption

Comment: @Zoya If you think that is a good article then you've just proven you completely missed the point about cryptography in general. Strange, your answer seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @Maarten Why? I read it and looked and the sample code. It was clear for me. I could understand how it works. But it would be great if you could explain a little bit why this code is bad or wrong about cryptography. ( i have to add that i have no knowledge about cryptography )

Comment: The security proofs of RSA rely on the padding used. This one uses a few (too few) bytes of padding, and the proprietary scheme has no security proof.

Comment: Besides, this is what is called a signature with message recovery. There are comparable *broken and withdrawn* schemes in ISO/IEC 9796-2. It's not called encryption. If the author does not know this, he shouldn't be presenting his code, especially not without indicating why the attacks won't work on his particular scheme.

Comment: This senario for app licensing is valid and I am not sure why people are surprised. Other frameworks allow 2 way encryption/decryption

Comment: I end up using bouncycastle .NET
https://newbedev.com/c-bouncycastle-rsa-encryption-with-public-private-keys

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use signature generation, In which **the private key is used to generate a signature that verifies that your message is authentic.**

```
// Create message and signature on your end
string message = "Here is the license message";

var converter = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] plainText = converter.GetBytes(message);

var rsaWrite = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var privateParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(true);

// Generate the public key / these can be sent to the user.
var publicParams = rsaWrite.ExportParameters(false);

byte[] signature =
    rsaWrite.SignData(plainText, new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

// Verify from the user's side. Note that only the public parameters
// are needed.
var rsaRead = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsaRead.ImportParameters(publicParams);
if (rsaRead.VerifyData(plainText,
                       new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(),
                       signature))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Verified!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NOT verified!");
}
```

you can take further help from [HERE](https://web.archive.org/web/20150722054844/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2006/09/19/761726.aspx)

Comment: I've removed the term "signature strategy" as I've never heard of signature generation to be described that way.

Comment: What if you wish to actually encrypt the data -- not just validate it's authenticity using a hash ?

Comment: @Syeda "Generate the public key / these can be sent to the user" Can you explain how ? What do I do with the RSAParameters object ? Thanks

Comment: link is now dead

Comment: @RubensFarias I added a link to an archive copy

Comment: For those who came from Google. This code example signs and verifies data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.signdata?view=net-8.0