# How to encrypt by private key in c# (RSA)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, bouncycastle

here is what i want to do

**1. create public ,private key pair for encryption**

**2. encrypt data by private key**

**3. decrypt data by public key**

i want to encrypt data by private key so that encrypted data i send to anyone
could be decrypted by my public key
ensuring data is coming from me

here is what i have right now
i am using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();  
var   privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);  
var  publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
  var text = "my messege";
  Console.WriteLine("RSA // Text to encrypt: " + text);
  var enc = Encrypt(text, publicKey);
  Console.WriteLine("RSA // Encrypted Text: " + enc);
  var dec = Decrypt(enc, privateKey);
  Console.WriteLine("RSA // Decrypted Text: " + dec);
```

**my methods**
**for decryption**

```
 public static string Decrypt(string data,string pvtK)
                  {
                      var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                      var dataArray = data.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                      byte[] dataByte = new byte[dataArray.Length];
                      for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
                      {
                          dataByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(dataArray[i]);
                      }

                      rsa.FromXmlString(pvtK);
                      var decryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(dataByte, false);

                      return _encoder.GetString(decryptedByte);
                  }
```

**for encryption**

```
  public static string Encrypt(string data,string pubK)
                  {
                      var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                      rsa.FromXmlString(pubK);
                      var dataToEncrypt = _encoder.GetBytes(data);
                      var encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false).ToArray();
                      var length = encryptedByteArray.Count();
                      var item = 0;
                      var sb = new StringBuilder();
                      foreach (var x in encryptedByteArray)
                      {
                          item++;
                          sb.Append(x);

                          if (item < length)
                              sb.Append(",");
                      }

                      return sb.ToString(); 
                  }
```

currently its working fine when encrypting by public key and decrypting by private key

**now i have two concern when decrypting by private key**

1. When i pass my private key to encrypt my message it got decrypted but  when i pass my public key to decrypt that data i got wrong key exception and not working
2. in `RSACryptoServiceProvider` private key is a combo of Public and private how do i know which is my actual private key as its in the xmlFormat making it really difficult to identify what does every thing mean in the key

**here is my private key**

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>sHQOnB9obOy9UUvKolGBYUHyGNKXKC7ZqerB/pLQcOKKlhqXAB5KLPf62banbC5DLU5+Mhd25sq5KE5l/vEZeQLia+np2TYwis8bNVQpLYh/Q2MmuldKzl4Al+ziVH90NLe0fX6LiC5W9Q36HkzV16BKrHwLPljNNBNYWENl/p8=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>vGAPI9BTSnOvVKQ9spTt7WaCb3j+Dexy48VHbGV2+h1hKEA7pF4Mrog7VL7MCNp8G8XZIWh3sMa9VHn2bNv0mQ==</P><Q>78xcUFFtngtKxpr6pZssiXIlTThFo7X2zRiUsWLSUKDJlYlGELu8cGAxzbRYirk2psm92Fga1jAPNDhuzpVX9w==</Q><DP>dHcThTn89RAXO8ab2riXbequBEuTD3q8AbTsFsmYyMS3WBJ2jYYUYygZPqkELwkeKHGncC9NqP8G+Z66S82mKQ==</DP><DQ>C7Zel+myQfLpPxQYw/f1T+1MVx41gI6FtHTL5nIeNaP01KH00yJoTNDV/eceIAB14+WcqTF8dhO42mMbPmna9w==</DQ><InverseQ>ORoUweiOyF+eEQ3F3+NU2IdcSYM5TRG/J73er1nBuyfz5QjKpOhSWqtl5W3mNmQmX8/WDv9bFzgE0jPdXQtFTQ==</InverseQ><D>B/agGpHcs7gpdFJNCYjpI5UHOPFdt6DWdPGVCLxI4oqIaG04Lfd8yU1cIyUE2eaEMWn1J9iUQEBoHWmp9vJozLbhzUdQUC+tcrms4dys6U+AhLTJ+obpmlJczdVABSWlwFe1lnoJNqJN9QQyc4tVvcLKzy+YPbhHvb66bfhVcqk=</D></RSAKeyValue>
```

Comment: *Textbook* RSA says signing and encrypting are the same operations. *Practical, usable* RSA uses different operations/options for encrypting and signing so if you want signing (which I think you do - "ensuring data is coming from me"), go looking for that, not encryption.

Comment: Also, your choice of method for "stringifying" the result is questionable - comma separated decimal representation of numbers is really *inefficient* compared to e.g. Base 64 encoding. (Your encoding blows up the size of the data by between 100% and 300%. Base 64 encoding gets you ~ 40%)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could please tell even its possible to encrypt data by private key while using RSACryptoServiceProvider  Class ?

Comment: You use `SignData` or `SignHash`, not `Encrypt`. And then use `Verify` variants at the othed end.

Comment: please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578694/how-to-encrypt-with-private-key-and-decrypt-with-public-key-in-c-sharp-rsa

Comment: here he is verifying signature by rsa class what if user is not on .NET plateform]

Comment: *every* sane library that supports private key at sender -> public key at receiver will expose that as Sign/Verify methods (may not have those names). If they also support public key -> private key they'll have Encrypt/Decrypt methods. To make things **safe**, you can't use textbook RSA that says signing and encryption are the same thing. You have to have four different operations. This isn't a ".NET thing" this is a cryptographic security thing. If you don't understand this, then with all due respect, you shouldn't be writing crypto code.

Comment: thanks man you were really helpful btw nice advice!